# Permission Dialog button label is "Go to app" instead of "Login with Facebook"

Tags: javascript, facebook, spring

I have a page with a "Login with Facebook" button. (We use Java+Spring Social).
If user clicks on this button it submits the form for: /social/signin/facebook
The Permission Dialog opens, but the Button's label on it is "Go to app". What should I do to make this label be "Login with Facebook" and not "Go to app"? I tried the display:popup parameter, but the label was the same with it.

In another project we don't use Spring Source. We make the Fb login with this call:

```
FB.login(
  function(response) {
    if(response.authResponse) {
      window.location = ...
    } else {
      alert(accessDeniedMessage);                                                 
    }
},{scope : REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS});
```

and this case the button in the Permission Dialog is "Login with Facebook".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/03/02/enhanced-auth-dialog-and-updates-to-permissions/

> **New button text**
>
> In the enhanced auth dialog, the button text will be one of four
>   cases: "Add to Facebook", "Log in with Facebook", “Go to App”, or
>   "Play Game". Each of these were extensively tested and showed that
>   more specific calls to action help users better understand the auth
>   process. As the first point of contact for an app, it’s important for
>   the auth dialog to exhibit a great user experience.
>
> See our [Open Graph documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/) to learn more about permissions and
>   configuring the enhanced auth dialog.

Comment: I read this link but i couldn't find any description about how does Fb  find out which text suites for the page for the 4 available:  "Add to Facebook", "Log in with Facebook", “Go to App”, or "Play Game"

Comment: Here's what Lu Chen said in the comments for that blog post:  `- if the user has already installed the app and you are requesting additional permissions that includes "publish_actions", we use "Add to Facebook"
- if you're a game app, we use "Play Game"
- if your auth dialog is shown in display=popup (e.g. after user clicks a "Log In with Facebook" fb:login button), we use "Log In with Facebook"
- in other situations, we use "Go to App"`

Comment: display=popup is not working with SpringSocial (The label is NOT 'Login with Facebook' with it)

Comment: You should contact SpringSocial for issues/bugs with their framework.  If you're not required to use SpringSocial, code it up yourself to get at your requirements.  It's really not hard at all.